# How find this function $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-2x}+\sqrt{2x^2-3x+3}$ range

Tags: inequality

let $x\in R$,and 
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-2x}+\sqrt{2x^2-3x+3}$$
find the $f(x)$ range

My idea: since 
$$x^2-2x\ge 0,2x^2-3x+3\ge 0$$
$$\Longrightarrow x\ge 2,or, x\le 0$$

I use mathmatices give this reslut $$f(x)\ge \sqrt{3}$$ can see this
 [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28x%5E2-2x%29%2Bsqrt%282x%5E2-3x%2B3%29&dataset=&equal=Submit)

Comment: You got the domain x<0 || x>2 correct. You can check the values of $f(x)$ at the boundaries of the domain, and check, if the function has any local minima anywhere else. This way you get all the candidates for a global minimum. For the upper bound, the range is obviously infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions, $x\geq 2$ and $x\leq0$, are conditions $x$ must satisfy in order for $f(x)$ to be defined, meaning that $(-\infty, 0]\cup[2,\infty)$ is the domain od $f$.

In order to find the range of $f$, you must find the maximum and minimum of $f(x)$ on each interval of its domain.

- On $(-\infty, 0]$ the function is decreasing (because its derivative is negative), meaning it takes all the values on $\displaystyle[f(0), \lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)) = [\sqrt3, \infty)$.
- On $[2,\infty)$, the function is increasing, taking all the values on $\displaystyle[f(2), \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)) = [\sqrt5, \infty)$.